# Is it possible to run two functions concurrent to each other?

Tags: python, praw

I have two functions, both of them are getting an output from a generator using a for loop.

```
for comment in subreddit.stream.comments():
    <code goes here>
```

There is another function that works in exactly the same way and I would like to be able to switch between them.

For example, if the generator from function A is not yielding anything, then I would like to switch over to function B, and go back to A when B is not yielding anything.

The program is supposed to run indefinitely.

Comment: What if both A and B are not yielding? By "not yielding anything" what do you mean? Does this mean that the generator is "too long" to yield or that it has ended its "sequence"? I guess it is not the latter because you want them to yield indefinitely. Depending on these responses, you could implement an iterator other iterators A and B that switch between them depending some conditions (here the condition will be "the first one that is yielding something")

Answer (score 0):

You should run the two for loops on two separate threads. But the items into a queue. Then iterate over the queue on your main thread.